# React-Native: Trying to use custom XML into AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating an Android app in React-Native, and I have a problem with a fetch with an API for the signup. So, I tried creating a file in `android/app/src/main/assets/xml`

react_native_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
   <domain includeSubdomains="false">MyDomain</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And I add it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/react_native_config"> // THERE
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

But when I compile the app I receive this error:

```
android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: error: resource xml/react_native_config not found
```

Do you know How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use fetch API in react native you don't need to add XML file.Just Enable Internet permission like this

```
<manifest>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

and use fetch API as-

GET-

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

POST-

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```